# MCU controlled adjusting LED current with current sensing regulators?

Tags: linear-regulator

I'm really sorry for the noobly formulated question, if I knew how to formulate it I'd probably find what I need by searching, this has to have been asked and dealt with many times.

I've been using some regulators / LED drivers (CAT4101 for example) where I can easily adjust the current from a MCU by using a digipot. The sense resistor is between sense pin on the regulator and GND. To obtain max specified current for the CAT4101 the resistor needs to be 549 ohm. With a 256 step 5K digipot in series with a resistor (549 - wiper resistance) I can control the current easily with good enough resolution.

Now I've been looking at some other regulators of interest but they require current sensing resistor to be in series with the LEDs. Is there a similarly easy method to adjust current with these kind of regulators? I can't seem to find a method of doing it.

Note: I know I can use PWM to adjust LED brightness. I'm not asking about that.

Comment: Depends on the regulator. Some will compare the voltage across the sense resistor with a reference voltage to adjust the output. Which one are you looking at?

Comment: I think an approach like mentioned here should work: [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248135/inexpensive-circuit-architecture-for-power-supply-voltage-adjustment)

Comment: One of the regulators I am looking at is the CN5501: http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN5501.pdf

Comment: I'll have to read through that link, thanks. A lot of it is currently beyond me though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is being rude and not updating his question with facts that he chooses to put as comments.

Comment: The question is on topic. You're deleted "answer" wasn't.